# iphone: keyboard is not hiding

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uialertview, resignfirstresponder

I have a situation, I have an alertview with one textfield drawn in it programmatically

```
UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"Enter you name" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];

    [nameField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [nameField setPlaceholder:@"Enter Owners name"];
    [nameField setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [nameField setDelegate:self];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [alertView addSubview:nameField];
    CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -80.00);
    [alertView setTransform: moveUp];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
```

to hide the keyboard I have used this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}

but keyboard is not hiding. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide your keyboard using this. This will work when clicking the background of your simulator/emulator/iOS-device.

```
  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

            [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];

            // you can have multiple textfields here


        }
```

Comment: Hey this is cool, i was using a invisible uibutton to hide the keyboard. Just a question, does it work on any view controller? Or dow we need to do something extra?

Comment: This should be able to be done in any viewcontroller without much modification at all.
Also feel free to mark my answer as accepted next to the the answer. :)